# How to include rows from an Access query/form in a VBA generated emails?

Tags: vba, email, row

How do I include rows from an Access query/form in a VBA generated emails?

I currently send the forms as attachments, but not every client has Excel, so that's why I want to include it in the e-mail body, which is HTML, I think.

This is my code:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub btnMail_Click()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim MailTo, Subj, Att, Att2, Att3 As String

MailTo = "myemail@gmail.com"
Subj = "Test mail"
Content = "Private content"
Att = "C:\Users\min stock.xls"
Att2 = "C:\Users\todo.txt"
Att3 = "C:\Users\Stockmanagementv3.accdb"



staff = "Kind regards" & vbCrLf & "My company"
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .To = MailTo
    .Subject = Subj & Now & " Mail "
    .Body = Content & staff

    .Attachments.Add Att
    .Attachments.Add Att2
    .Attachments.Add Att3

.send
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
MsgBox ("Your mail has been sent succesfully!")
End Sub
```

Comment: you can export the query into a html file and then attach the html file in your email? or do you want to read each row and write in the email?

Comment: I can do the first, but I want to do the latter because that's easier for some clients of our company. So basically write the rows into the body part of the email if that's somehow possible.

Comment: IMO, exporting a query into a html, attach the file send as email is much easier than reading and creating mail merge kind of email.
you can do the export, add and send all via vba

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'll try to do that now. Is it ok to contact you if I happen to have any errors?

Comment: I spent some time on Google but the best thing I could find was .htmlbody, but nothing related to converting a query to html. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in my comment you could save the query as html file

```
dim FN as String 
fn = "C:\myQuery.html"

'SAve the query as html file
docmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qry_name", acFormatHTML, fn

'add the file as attachment
.Attachments.Add fn
```

hope this helps..